# Django: how to save data to database in django when a condition is met?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am writing a logic to allow user pay for items using thier debit card, the logic is working fine. Now i want to save some data to the database when the `status=successful`.

When a user purchase a course i want to add the `course` and the `user` who purchased the course to a model that i have created called `UserCourse`.

I have tried adding slug to the `process_payment` view that i created but it seems not to be working. I also have another view called `payment_response` that checks if a payment was success or not.

How do i add the purchased `course` and the `user` that purchase the course in the db?

views.py

```
# The course detail view
def course_details(request, course_slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)


@login_required
def course_checkout(request, slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    user = request.user
    
    # form to get the student's name, email, amount of course
    if request.method == "POST":
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        amount = request.POST.get("amount")
        return redirect(str(process_payment(name,email,amount, course)))
        else:
            pass

    # how to handle courses that are free
    if amount == 0:
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
        userCourse = UserCourse(user=user, course=course)
        userCourse.save()
        return redirect('course:course-content', course.slug)

# View that processes the payment
def process_payment(name,email,amount):
     auth_token= settings.FLUTTER_SECRET_KEY
     hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
     data = {
                "tx_ref":''+str(math.floor(1000000 + random.random()*9000000)),
                "amount":amount,
                "currency":"USD",
                "redirect_url":"http://localhost:8000/callback",
                "payment_options":"card",
                "meta":{
                    "consumer_id":23,
                    "consumer_mac":"92a3-912ba-1192a"
                },
                "customer":{
                    "email":email,
                    # "phonenumber":phone,
                    "name":name
                },
                "customizations":{
                    "title":"DexxaEd",
                    "description":" Limitless Learning For Everyone",
                    "logo":"https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg"
                }
                }
     url = ' https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/payments'
     response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
     response=response.json()
     link=response['data']['link']
     return link

# view that check for payment status

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def payment_response(request):
    status=request.GET.get('status', None)
    tx_ref=request.GET.get('tx_ref', None)
    print(status)
    print(tx_ref)
    
    if status == "successful":
        # return HttpResponse('Payment Successful')
        return render(request, "payment/payment-success.html")
    if status == "cancelled":
        return render(request, "payment/payment-failed.html")
        # return HttpResponse('Payment Cancelled')
```

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    course_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Model that store the purchased courses

class UserCourse(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , null = False , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usercourse")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py

```
    path('callback', payment_response, name='payment_response')
```

Comment: add boolean paid field in UserCourse; For free course made it True and for paid course update to True if payment is successful.

Comment: @ShishirSubedi how do i get the exact course that is being paid for in the `payment_response` view?

Comment: you can pass it as a get params or post data like you passing status and user id also; then filter usercourse with couse id and user id and update paid field.

Comment: @ShishirSubedi please i request one thing from you, show me a code example of how to achieve, i don't know how to go about writing the logic.

Comment: I don't know it will work or not just giving you idea. I will give snippet in the answer section

Comment: @ShishirSubedi yes i understand, okay i will be wating txns alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update your UserCourse to include paid field as

```
class UserCourse(models.Model):
    # your previous fields
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the course checkout function create usercourse object if it is a free couse paid is set True else False

```
def course_checkout(request, slug):
    # previous code
    if request.method == "POST":
        # your existing code
        user_course = UserCourse.objects.create(user=user, course=course)
        user_course_id = user_course.id
        # your existing code
        return redirect(str(process_payment(name, email, amount, course, user_course_id)))
        # your other code logic
    if amount == 0:
        user_course = UserCourse.objects.create(user=user, course=course, paid=True)
        # your other code logic
```

In the payment_response function provide user_course_id url arguments as

```
def payment_response(request, user_course_id=None):
    status=request.GET.get('status', None)
    tx_ref=request.GET.get('tx_ref', None) 
    if status == "successful":
        if user_course_id:
            UserCourse.objects.filter(id=user_course_id).update(paid=True)
            return render(request, "payment/payment-success.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "payment/payment-failed.html")
    if status == "cancelled":
        return render(request, "payment/payment-failed.html")
```

In the process payment view;

```
def process_payment(name, email, amount, course, user_course_id):
    # your existing code only change redirection url in data as
    {
        "redirect_url":f"http://localhost:8000/callback/{user_course_id}/",
    }
```

In urls.py

```
path('callback/<int:user_course_id>/', payment_response, name='payment_response')
```

Comment: that solved it for me. you saved my ass! txks brother. Nice blog posts tho from your website

Comment: What if you are using POST method to send form field data to the database, how will you achieve that if status == 'successful' ?

Comment: @oriohac request.POST.get("status")